# Foreign keys work occasionally in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am quite new to StackOverflow so please sorry in the case I am doing something wrong. And sorry for my English - it's not my native language.

Ok, make long story short. I am using:

```
 Server version: 5.6.31 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

There I have two tables like this:

**Table texts**

```
CREATE TABLE `texts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `body` text,
  `source_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `texts_sources_key` (`source_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `texts_sources_key` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `texts` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**table texts_sources**

```
CREATE TABLE `texts_sources` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `short_desc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `long_desc` text,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

As you can see - there is foreign key linking these tables with *ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE*.

Here is initial  data:

```
mysql> select * from texts;
+----+------+-----------+
| id | body | source_id |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | ***  |         1 |
+----+------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from texts_sources;
+----+------------+-----------+----------------+
| id | short_desc | long_desc | url            |
+----+------------+-----------+----------------+
|  1 | *          | NULL      | http://url.com |
+----+------------+-----------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now let's do some magic.

```
mysql> update texts_sources set id=5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from texts_sources;
+----+------------+-----------+----------------+
| id | short_desc | long_desc | url            |
+----+------------+-----------+----------------+
|  5 | *          | NULL      | http://url.com |
+----+------------+-----------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from texts;
+----+------+-----------+
| id | body | source_id |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | ***  |         1 |
+----+------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Not working. Some more fun:

```
mysql> delete from texts_sources;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.18 sec)

mysql> select * from texts;
+----+------+-----------+
| id | body | source_id |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | ***  |         1 |
+----+------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Not working. Ok. Maybe it is not working at all. Let's then try this way:

```
mysql> update texts set source_id=5;
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`serj_by`.`texts`, CONSTRAINT `humor_sources_key` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `texts` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)
mysql> insert into texts (body, source_id) values ("***", 7);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`serj_by`.`texts`, CONSTRAINT `humor_sources_key` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `texts` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Working. Fun. Even funnier (texts_sources is empty, hope you remember):

```
mysql> insert into texts (body, source_id) values ("***", 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> select * from texts_sources;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from texts;
+----+------+-----------+
| id | body | source_id |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | ***  |         1 |
|  2 | ***  |         1 |
+----+------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So my question is obvious. What it was? And how make it working in all cases as expected? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a close look at this:

```
CONSTRAINT `texts_sources_key` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) 
    REFERENCES `texts` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Though you have named this as `texts_sources_key` the foreign key actually references a column in the same table. You probably intended it to be

```
CONSTRAINT `texts_sources_key` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) 
    REFERENCES `texts_sources` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

additionally you would need to create the text_sources table first before you make that constraint.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was started thinking I am insane. Works like a charm! What a pity mistake...

Comment: glad to have helped